# Div display for a minimum of 1s, or until the main content is loaded - whichever comes first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented the below script that ensures a preloader page is displayed on my website homepage until the main page content is fully loaded.

I'd like to adapt the below to ensure the preloader always appears for a minimum amount of time (i.e 1s) to ensure it always displays, even on fast connections. The preloader should display for a minimum of 1s, or until the main content is loaded - whichever comes first. Is this possible?

**HTML**

```
<div class='preloader'>
    <div class="preloader-logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="preloader-loading-icon">Loading</div>
</div>

<main>Content goes here, should be hidden initially until fully loaded (or 1s have lapsed).</main>
```

**JS**

```
/* Preloader Splash */
$(window).load(function(){
    $('main').animate({opacity: 1},300);
    $('.preloader').fadeOut(500);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.preloader {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: rgba(255,102,51,1);
}

.preloader-logo {
    background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 -300px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    height: 58px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.preloader-loading-icon {
    background: url(images/preloader-loading.svg) no-repeat 50%;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 90px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: What is `#container` ?

Comment: how do you check if all content is loaded?

Comment: You are looking for a debounce function. This post may be useful http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: You could use *pace* and save yourself from re-inventing the wheel. http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Comment: @Abhitalks Sorry that was a mistake, I've updated the question

Comment: @messerbill via the JS in the question

Comment: @Abhitalks Unfortuantely that is a little more complex than I require, only want to do as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I like this but its a simple way of achieving what you are looking for:

```
var timedOut = false;
var loaded = false;

/* Preloader Splash */
$(window).load(function(){
    loaded = true;
    hideLoading();
});

setTimeout(function(){
    timedOut = true;
    hideLoading();
}, 1000);

function hideLoading(){
    if(loaded && timedOut){
        $('#container').animate({opacity: 1},300);
        $('.preloader').fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

This means that the load will only hide loading if 1s has passed and 1s will close the loading if the page is already loaded.

Original Answer:

You could display it for 1s after the page has finished loading:

```
/* Preloader Splash */
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#container').animate({opacity: 1},300);
        $('.preloader').fadeOut(500);
    , 1000);
});
```

There may be better ways as this means even on slow loading pages it will be 1s after finished loading rather than straight away. So load time + 1s rather than load time or 1s

Comment: i don't think this is very beutiful, it would be better to ckeck for a real loading status

Comment: It would and that would probably sort the waiting for 1s after the slow load as well but I'm just suggesting a way he could do it with the loaded status being checked as is in the question

Comment: The function is setTimeout no setTimeouf

Comment: Thanks @Dhunt, this is a useful solution but the risk of adding an additional 1s to every load, regardless of duration is something I'd rather avoid!

Answer (score 0):

Initially your main content `#container` **opacity** should be set to `0`, so that the animation could show any effect.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Code here executes when the whole content (with images etc) is loaded
});
```